# Counting different types of events within 1 week cycles

Tags: r

I have data on hundreds of people in an ongoing study. New people are added daily to this growing cohort. I am trying to count the number of actions within each weekly cycle, where a cycle begins every Tuesday morning. Cycles do not overlap.

Everyone is emailed a yes/no question at the beginning of a cycle. If they don't answer within 24 hours, they are emailed the question again on Wednesday. The question is emailed a third time on Thursday if they don't respond within 24 hours of the second email. A phone call is placed if no response is received within 24 hours after the third email ("Phone call").

My data set looks like this:

```
participant <- c(rep('A', 5), 'B', 'B', rep('C', 3), rep('D', 4), rep('E', 4))
datetime <- c('12/31/19 8:44', '12/31/19 8:45', '1/1/20 9:52', '1/1/20 13:12', '1/2/20 9:53', '12/31/19 8:44', 
              '1/1/20 9:03', '12/31/19 8:44', '1/1/20 9:25', '1/2/20 9:53', '12/31/19 8:44', '1/1/20 9:50',
              '1/2/20 9:53', '1/3/20 9:50', '12/31/19 8:44', '1/1/20 9:50', '1/2/20 9:55', '1/3/20 9:55')
event <- c('Email sent', rep('Yes', 4), 'Email sent', 'Yes', 'Email sent', 'No', 'No', rep('Email sent', 3),
           'Phone call', rep('Email sent', 3), 'Phone call')

df <- data.frame(participant, time = strptime(datetime, "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"), event)
df <- df[order(df$time), ]
```

Participants who answer their email(s) are represented in the data with a "Yes" or a "No". Participants can also respond more than once within the same cycle. For simplicity, assume a participant's multiple responses within a cycle are all the same.

One challenge is that the data set does not distinguish between Emails 1, 2 and 3 (they are all coded as "Email sent"). Another challenge is how to deal with cycles that span the end of one month (or year) and the beginning of another (or year).

For each cycle, I would like to know:

1. How many participants responded only once?
2. How many participants provided multiple responses?
3. How many participants did not provide any response?

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what to do with tabulating "Email sent" or "Phone call", but once you understand this code you should be able to adjust it. Here I assumed "Yes" or a "No" was a response:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df %>% 
  # this will round each date back to the most recent Tuesday and then takes the week number
  dplyr::mutate(week = lubridate::floor_date(time, unit = "week", week_start = 2) %>% 
                  lubridate::week()) %>% 
  # for each participant and week number count each event
  tidyr::pivot_wider(id_cols = c(participant, week),
                     names_from = event, # event names become columns
                     values_from = event,
                     values_fn = length # count of events become column values
) %>% 
  # replace NA with 0 -- NA means a certain particpant, week, event combination wasnt observed
  dplyr::mutate_at(dplyr::vars(-participant, -week), ~ tidyr::replace_na(., 0)) %>% 
  dplyr::rowwise() %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(responses = Yes + No) %>% # count number of "Yes"/"No" for each row
  dplyr::ungroup() %>%
  dplyr::group_by(week) %>% 
  # get summary tabulations for each week
  dplyr::summarize(only_once = sum(responses == 1), # count of those that responded once
                   multiple = sum(responses > 1), # count of those that responded multiple times
                   no_response = sum(responses == 0)) # count of those that did not respond
```

Using `lubridate::floor_date` to round back to the most recent Tuesday and then using the week number as a unique identifier takes care of the issue of the cycle spanning across months. If you're collecting data across years then you could easily write a conditional statement based on the year (using `lubridate::year`) and week of the date.

Comment: This worked!! I really appreciate your help. I should become more familiar with the tidyverse dialect. I wish my upvote for you could be made public but my account is too new.